# Hi I would like to know if modules (2gb each) of G Skill F3-12800CL7 are compatible with Intel® NUC Kit D34010WYK

Tags: memory, ddr3, voltage

I would like to know if modules (2gb each) of G Skill F3-12800CL7 are compatible with 
Intel NUC Kit D34010WYK.
That because of the voltage: the NUC does not support 1,5 V but only 1,35 V.
I would like to know if the above mentioned modules can work at 1,35 V.
The Module Nominal Voltage (VDD) is 1.5 V as reported by HWINFO.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some information - http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-034586.htm

So it would seem that the GSkill memory is not supported as it's 1.5V